# How to synchronize downloaded emails from clients back to the IMAP server

Tags: synchronization, imap, postfix-mta, data-recovery, dovecot

I have an iRedMail server running (postfix + dovecot as an IMAP server) on a Debian Xen guest machine. By a mistake the iscsi disk, where users emails are stored, was deleted. There is another copy of this disk from December 30th 2014. There is a full backup of users email from January 16th 2015. So all user emails from the beginning to January 16th were restored.

The problem is when users open their email clients and the synchronization process with IMAP server begins all downloaded emails from January 16th till today (January 31th) will be deleted from their machines. **How should I configure dovecot IMAP server so that these emails will be synchronized back to the IMAP server?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. The client is considered a local cache of the server state. You cannot configure the server in some way to evade this. If you have a small number of users, you could ask them to make a local copy of their emails by copying into a local folder. They can then copy them back later, which will generally upload back to the server.

Comment: But when some people try to copy downloaded emails to a local folder, they get the error that IMAP server is unavailable, and emails can't be copied. How should I work around this?

Comment: That probably means they hadn't actually downloaded the whole message.  If they don't have it and you don't have it, sounds like they're SOL.